# installing LTTNG on Rasberry pi or Beaglebone black

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, beagleboneblack, lttng

I am trying to install LTTNG tracing tool on raspberry pi and beaglebone black board. I have searched online and have not seem to found any tutorial that successfully does this. The official LTTNG documentation does not work on these devices. Does anyone know of any tutorial? Thanks.

Comment: Depends on your Linux distribution, actually, not on the device itself. What is it?

Comment: Hello. It is ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus)